# angular5 how to make asyc request?

Tags: asynchronous, request, angular5, observable, response

> In my project i made multiple request to server to get data for single page. I want to make all request asyc. Right now until i get the response from first request,the response of second request is not load.

So basically i just want to achive asyc request and response so one request will not wait for other request to finish.
Right now it's like first come first serve fashion.
But i want from multiple request which request get first response should load first.

this is code of my component

```
  constructor(private _dashboardService: DashboardService) {

  this.getLineChart();
  this.todayPaymentDetails();
  this.todayPaymentMethod();
  this.rewardCustomers();
  this.getAverageBill();
  this.getItemByVolumn();
  this.getItemBySales();
} 

todayPaymentMethod(id=null){
  this.paymentMethodsLoader=0;
  this._dashboardService.getTodayPaymentMethod(id).subscribe(res =>{
    if(null != res.data && '' != res.data){
      this.location = res.data.location;
      this.payment_methods = res.data.payment_methods;
    }
    this.paymentMethodsLoader=1;
  });
}
```

this is my service code:

```
getTodayTotalPayment(id)  : Observable<any> {
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this._http.get(environment.apiUrl + constants.API_V1 + 'today-total-payment/'+id, options)
.map(res => res.json())
.catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || error));
```

}

Here shows code for only one request but as shown in constructor i send multiple request at a time.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst it is not a good practise to call function like this in constructor.

For running multiple request or observable together use operators i.e. switchMap etc.

Follow this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=1395s) related to event loop in JavaScript this will improve your JavaScript execution , event loop concepts . also explains how asynchronous code executed.

Hope it will help.

Comment: @pal check now.